# How to get DAG information from within a task in Python & Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Is there a way to obtain the dag_id from a DAG in Airflow from within one of its tasks in Python?

My purpose is to delete a table (that has been created with the same name of the dag) inside a Task.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. You can do it via Jinja macros if you have templated field https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html#macros-reference
2. same macros are available in the form of `context` dictionary passed to `execute` method of your operator.

Comment: To add upon that. In the `context` it's thereby available by the `task` and `dag` macro. Both contain `dag_id` as attribute. E.g. If you have a function with context, it's `context['task'].dag_id`.